# Trying to send any function as a parameter and deduce type?

Tags: c++

I want to pass a function as parameter to wrapper function which executes that function, calculates execution time and prints it, and then return that function's return value.Here is what i tried to do so far.

```
#include  <functional>
#include <chrono>

namespace TimeIt {

template <typename T>
auto time_it(std::string name, std::function<T> work) -> decltype(work()) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto return_value = work();
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    printf("Time taken by function:%s is %lld",name, duration.count());

    return return_value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is `void`.  Using `std::function` is harmful here, as it adds needless overhead.

```
template<class F>
struct scope_guard_t {
  F f;
  ~scope_guard_t() noexcept(noexcept(f())
  {
    f();
  }
};
template<class F>
scope_guard_t<std::decay_t<F>> scope_guard(F&&f){
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}

template<class F>
auto time_it(std::string name, F&& f)
-> std::result_of_t<F&&()>
{
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  auto wrapup = scope_guard([&]{
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    printf("Time taken by function:%s is %lld",name, duration.count());
  });      
  return std::forward<F>(f)();
}
```

there we go.

Answer (score 2):

It's actively harmful to try to wrap everything in `std::function` here, you should just let the raw callable type be deduced.

```
template <typename Callable, typename ... Args>
auto time_it(std::string name, Callable&& work, Args&&... args) -> std::invoke_result_t<Callable, Args...> {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto return_value = std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(work), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    printf("Time taken by function:%s is %lld",name, duration.count());

    return return_value;
}
```